# Suggestions for a replacement garage door opener

Tags: product-recommendation, replacement, garage-door-opener

My garage door opener has finally failed and I need to buy a replacement. I'm looking for suggestions on the pros and cons of different types of openers.

Here are the details of the current setup:

1. Fiberglass 2-car garage door. (It is about as basic as you can get, no windows, no extra weight, etc).
2. It is **NOT** located anywhere that noise is an issue (below a bedroom for example).
3. I am not opposed to chain drive as that is what I have, but I've been looking at either belt or screw drive. Smooth beats noise in this case, see #2 above.
4. One car has an integrated opener button and the other car will need a remote. There is also a need to add on a couple extra remotes for friends/family access.

What type of garage door opener would be best for this situation?

Comment: Welcome to DIY.StackExchange.  This is a question and answer site for Home Improvement and DIY questions, it is not an online shopping network nor is it a product recommendation/review site.  If you would like somebody to locate and sell a garage door opener to you, try the local hardware store or a garage door opener dealer.  If you have a specific question about the installation, and/or pros and cons of different types of garage door openers, feel free to ask that type of question. As for asking the community to shop for you, that type of question is off topic here.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more generic.

Comment: @Tester101 - Thanks for the clarification on the usage and the edit of my question. I should have known better as I frequent some of the other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

you won't find pricing suggestions here. pricing recommendations become out of date too quickly.

in my experience, if you're looking for smooth operation then you need to concentrate on the door. make sure it opens and closes smoothly. a bad garage opener will still open a well-adjusted door smoothly, but a good opener won't help a poorly adjusted door.

that being said, i really love my genie screw drive. they make a couple of models that open the door 2-3 times faster than it closes.

Comment: The door is in good shape and was serviced (greased, adjusted), but the opener has an internal broken part that would be foolish to spend the money to replace. It makes more sense to get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I know the people involved in the http://www.youdoitstore.com/ site, and would recommend them for DIY purchases.  Unfortunately, they don't seem to stock my favorite garage door opener though (The LiftMaster Formula 1 Whisper Drive).  Not only quiet (which you don't really care about anyways), but very smooth operation.